# Bypass '\' in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, escaping

What is the equivalent of
`string c# = @"\hello"`
in python? 
`python = '\hello'` 
In other words, how would I bypass the `'\''` breakpoint in python?

Comment: What do you mean by `bypass` ? if it means just getting the `hello` string then you can try `'\hello'.split('\\')[1]`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean that you want `\` to not act like an escape character, then you simply escape `\` with another `\`:

```
myString = "\\hello"
print myString
```

This prints:

```
\hello
```

You also can use a "raw" string:

```
myString = r"\hello"
```

Answer (score 2):

> "I am 6'2\" tall."  # escape double-quote inside string
>
> 'I am 6\'2"
>   tall.'  # escape single-quote inside string

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A **general rule of thumb** in any programming language to print the escape character or use it as a part of string is to escape the escape character. 
So

```
>>print "\\hello"
\hello
```

Also as pointed by @IanPudney , python provides a special mechanism to print the raw string. Just use ***print r"\hello"***

I hope this helps